# how to configure a git server to share projects

Tags: eclipse, git, egit, vmware-workstation

I currently have Fedora 17 inside a VM on my win7 computer. I want to configure the VM to manage my projects with git. I use eclipse helios on win7 with the egit plugin with my projects currently residing locally. Git and all the dependencies are already installed on the VM. The VM's hostname is dev.local and SSH is already installed, so I would use the following URL for access: ssh://john@dev.local:/php/projects/myframework.git

My question is, how do I initialize a new git repository on my VM and then push my local project up so that it's being managed by git in the VM?

Comment: just out of interest: if your development happens on your Win7 computer: why do you want to have your repos additionally in a VM? Do you know that you don't **have to** do that? Your local repos have all the information...

Comment: understood. the reason is due to wanting the code to reside on a linux environment in order to take advantage of continuous integration as well, which is much easier to configure those tools in linux. but, i am open to other ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, i finally figured it out. What I ended up doing was on my VM which is my Git server, was create my git directory:

`# mkdir /home/brett/myproject.git && cd /home/brett/myproject.git`

`# git init --bare`

On my client, in the project's folder (C:\www\myproject):

`# git init`

`# git add .`

`# git commit -m "Initial commit"`

`# git remote add origin ssh://brett@dev.local/myproject.git`

`# git push origin master`

I removed my client copy of the project and in eclipse, File > Import > Git > Project from Git, Select URI.

I plugged in the details to access the git repo on dev.local and was able to create a local copy in eclipse.

Anyways, thx everyone who took the time to reply to this. I actually found a decent article online which helped.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/EGit/article.html

Answer (score 0):

run a `git daemon` in your vm. The git protocol would make it easier for you.

Comment: Adam, do you have any reasons backing up the advantages of a git daemon? I have checked out the git protocols, and am using SSH since it's already configured and this is just a local development environment.

Comment: ssh+git:// is the standard protocol for git. You'll have the least issues configuring your environment using it. In fact, omitting the protocol in URLs specified in remote commands, defaults to this.

Comment: I would also take a look at gitolite.